# Adjust levels for RGB channels in Gimp python-fu?

Tags: python, gimp, python-fu

According to the docs I can access image channels via `channels` property but this gives me an empty list. I suspect only user-created channels are accessible via this property. How do I get a channel object for the R, G and B channels?

```
def python_myscript(img, drawable):
    print img.channels
>>> []
```

I need these channels to apply levels. I wanted to use presets but python-fu can't access these. That means I need to apply the level changes channel-by-channel, eg:

```
pdb.gimp_drawable_levels(layer, <CHANNEL NEEDED HERE>, ...)
```

I found there are channel constants. They don't give me an error but the result is "too white" and doesn't seem to matter which constant I use.

```
pdb.gimp_drawable_levels(layer, RED_CHANNEL, 0, 0.567, False, 1, 0, 1, False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the channel constants aren't appropriate to this usage. I looked at the procedure browser and the channel red actually maps to the integer 1 (HISTOGRAM-RED)

So to modify red channel levels

```
pdb.gimp_drawable_levels(layer, 1, 0, 0.567, False, 1, 0, 1, False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> According to the docs I can access image channels via channels property but this gives me an empty list.

This is really the list of explicitly created/saved channels (such as `Select > Save to channel`). The R/G/B/A channels at the top of the list are somewhat virtual, since they depend on layers modes and visibility.

Comment: Yeah I found that confusing. Internally gimp sometimes calls the RGB channels "components" but both the code and documentation mixes terminology as you can see in the procedure browser which calls the 2nd argument "channel" when it should really be called "component" to avoid exactly this sort of confusion.